# Was Voyager a Christmas ornament on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In *Star Trek:Voyager* - *Death Wish* ([S02E18](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode))), Quinn tries to hide himself and Voyager from Q. One hiding place he tried was to turn Voyager into a Christmas ornament hanging on a tree.

Were they on Earth at that time, and if so why would Quinn bring them all the way back to the Delta quadrant when he undid the shrinking? If he just put the ship back in space over Earth it seems he would be more likely to get the asylum he wanted.

Comment: The script doesn't say; "*NEW VIEWSCREEN ANGLE (OPTICAL)
To see we're an ornament on a Christmas tree. The branches and other
hanging balls and blinking lights are clearly visible. Suddenly we're
jolted... and everyone hangs on to keep from falling... and the picture
on the viewscreen pans as a hand picks us up, and now we see Q1's face
looking right into our viewscreen camera.*"

Comment: You might want to note that he seems to have moved the ship *outside of the universe* at one point. I would assume that moving it isn't a big deal to him

Comment: Great question.

Comment: I always thought that they missed a bet not using that clip to advertise Hallmark's Voyager ornament.

Comment: In my headcanon they were inside an ornament in Picard's Nexus fantasy. Seems like a much more obscure place to hide than earth.

Comment: @JohnMeacham - The tree looks different. The one in the Nexus fantasy is wrapped

Answer (score 3):

No, he wouldn't. Should he have put Voyager back on Earth, it wouldn't have been Janeway's choice to grant / reject Quinn asylum. It would've been up to the Federation. And with Picard's experiences with Q (de Lancie), they probably would not have been too fond to have a member of the Q continuum in their midst.

> "He's devious and amoral and unreliable and irresponsible and… and definitely not to be trusted."
>
> – Jean-Luc Picard, TNG S4E20

And as we know from *TNG:Attached* (S7E08):

> "We still plan to take our petition directly to the Federation Council! They'll listen-!"
>
> **"They will also listen to the reports of the Captain of the Enterprise and his First Officer!** And I can tell you right now the First Officer's report will go something like this: 'Kesprytt, a deeply troubled world with social, political, and military problems that they have yet to resolve. The Kes, while a friendly and democratic people, are driven by suspicion, deviousness, and paranoia. It is the opinion of this officer that they are not ready for membership.'"

They'll probably ask Picard for his opinion, as one of the only ones having had more than one contact with a Q. And Picard is not really fond of Q.

That they are not free of prejudice is shown every time they meet Q. Every time Q appears, Picard is less than thrilled. If humans were so evolved as they think they are, Picard wouldn't hold such a grudge against Q. Au contraire, he made Starfleet aware of the Borg. So, simply being inconvenient and having some jokes at Picard's cost was enough to make him unwelcome. That's perfectly normal but also shows that 24th century humans haven't really overcome the flaw of prejudice. And a Q *might* be more than just a little inconvenient for the Federation but a huge risk.

Comment: Is it the Federation way to judge an entire race based on an individual of that race?

Comment: @colmde Yes, as they're still human. And it's human nature to be cautious after bad experiences. Or how often do you have to touch something before believing it might hurt you.

Comment: Can you back this up with any evidence? Also they were an ornament *before* Q had agreed to an asylum hearing.

Comment: @Valorum I hope to have clarified my answer.

Comment: But it was Q2 not De Lancie wanting asylum. What value does Picard’s opinion have on him? The Kesprytt case is interesting if Q2 wanted membership, not sure how this would apply to asylum. Got me thinking...

Comment: I know a bit about how courts work and with no prior history “similar situations” like Kesprytt “could” become relevant to a request. They work with “preponderance of the evidence” - sometimes all you have is trivial “case law” to establish precedent (been in this situation actually). You think it’s apples and oranges, but the judge has nothing else...

Comment: @VogonPoet That's it. Up to Quinn, they only know De Lancie Q. And only Picard has this experience (AFAIK). So, it is a normal human behaviour to ask the one having met a Q. And it is also human to extrapolate from an experience to another. If you've been burned once by a fire, you wont need to touch every fire to assume it will burn you. To the contrary. There are cold flames burning at room temperature. It is quite the effort to touch it, even though you know it isn't hot. It's the same with Q. You got burnt once by a Q and you assume it's the same with all.

Comment: So we’ll never resolve what the Federation would decide, it’s all speculation. What your saying is Q2 doesn’t believe a Federation hearing would help him, therefore he would not bring Voyager home? He thought Voyager being trapped worked to his favor? Or he thought bringing Voyager home would be a “bribe” (which Q1 did)?

Comment: Both. It's easier just to handle one captain without access to the Federation than several admirals / bureaucrats / politicians which would undoubtetly become active when a being such as a Q requests asylum. What those people are willing to do to protect the federation is seen with Section 31. Janeway believes in the whole "humans live to better themselves and do the right thing". Admirals / politicians handling stuff done by Section 31 not. A being such a Q know this.