# Why have ships been resized in the newer Star Trek series or movies?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

In newer series or movies, starting from *Star Trek: 2009*, we have seen newly-designed or renovated ships that do not conform to any previous forms in the Star Trek universe.

The Original Enterprise was 289 meters, Excelsior class ships were 467 meters in length, Ambassador class ships measured 526 meters, Galaxy class ships were 642 meters long, and Sovereign class ships were 685 meters long.
(The reason I listed these ships is because they represent the design and schematic evolution of Starfleet ships.) As time passed, ships in Star Trek became more detailed, more advanced, and larger.

In 2009, there was the idea of rebooting *Star Trek* in an Alternate reality. The overall shape of the Enterprises in the original and Kelvin timelines were the same--but the feeling of the ship was quite different!

This comparison should definitely help you acquire the gist of the situation:

[image: The original Enterprise, against a pure black background.]

[image: A more modern-looking version of the original Enterprise, against a starry background.]

The new Enterprise is what you could call "more modern." I can accept that, but the schematics is a problem for me. The information of its size was released after the first movie, and it was a mess. Most sites and sources, ready to consume and absorb, or project any information that makes *Star Trek* seem more action-filled and "cool," claim that the new Enterprise is something around ***710 or 720 meters long!!*** However, the VFX and designs contradict that! This problem is perfectly explained in [this article](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/new_enterprise_comment.htm). You can find the information about the size of the new Enterprise under the heading, "The Enterprise Size Controversy."

When I learned of this, I was surprised and disappointed, because the new ST producers had disregarded the design lineage of *Star Trek.* So, I ignored it.

Then, after many years, came *Star Trek: Discovery.* Soon, I was searching for information on this new "Crossfield Class" ship. It is an astounding 750 meters long! I can understand that it is an experimental, powerful, science vessel, but it would absolutely dwarf the original Enterprise, even though it was built earlier! This is a link to [an image](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/dis-crossfield.jpg) that shows the starboard view of a Crossfield class.

Its length is dependent on its large, triangular secondary hull and long, linear nacelles, but it is unlikely that it was necessary for them to be *that* long. It would be uncommon for such a large ship to be made by the Federation in the 22nd century. However, if it's just U.S.S. Discovery, I can accept that.

Then came the Enterprise. This was the *third* "original" Enterprise to appear in *Star Trek*, and it was not too different from the "original" original Enterprise. Yet it was 442 meters long--a full 153 meters longer than the first Enterprise in *TOS.*

So these newer ships have been upscaled, directly contradicting the original facts and information concerning starships' schematics. Why have they been resized?

Comment: Ripply timey-wimey side-effects of the Narada time jump explain all the inconsistencies in-universe

Comment: I could have sworn that Q shrunk the Enterprise to a tiny toy size in some episode of TNG.

Comment: https://youtu.be/b19ryi7fRUE?t=75 that gives a fair look at the relative size of Discovery and Enterprise

Comment: Let's just say the actual model builders for the shooting models don't always go into the minutiae, like trying to estimate the deck height by the window size, and trying to extrapolate the overall length from THAT.

Comment: If [Ex Astris Scientia](https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/) can do it, then it's sad that the producers are too lazy to make things slightly reasonable. I'm counting the days 'til we meet Vulcans and get their help...

Comment: I'll also point out that the 750 m figure is NOT from a canon source, i.e. screen evidence, but at best, quasi-canon i.e. "STD Official Starship Collection" (from Eaglemoss?)

Comment: Well, there doesn't seem to be any feasible source with correct or reasonable information.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry If you're linking to EAS, and you've read it, you probably know everything there is to know about the subject. That site gets *very* in depth. what else do you expect to learn on SE?

Comment: Personally, I attribute the beefier ships an any other tech upgrades to a more intense militarization in the wake of the Xindi attack, which didn't happen in the original timeline.  But that's just me.

Comment: This reads more like a rant than a question

Comment: Is your comment an attempt to improve my question? If so, what would you like me to do?

Comment: There's quite a few times where shuttles seem way to big relative to their parent ship

Comment: @SpacePhoenix or the number of shuttles carried by various parent ships...

Comment: @Spencer It was a runabout in DS9 6x14: One Little Ship.

Comment: Because as time moves on, things get bigger because bigger is better. Even if time moved on to the past.

Comment: You can cut a lot of the fat out of this question - it's a perfectly valid one, but as Brian Ortiz says, reads like a rant.

Comment: Made edits and made my question "fit"...

Comment: @Spencer Also the Enterprise was shrunk to tiny toy size in *TOS* episodes "Requiem for Methuselah" and "Cat's Paw".

Comment: @Spencer A different member of the Q turned Voyager into a christmas ornament in the ST:VOY episode [_Death Wish_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Wish_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)). See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220975/was-voyager-a-christmas-ornament-on-earth).